# Calling function from other module does not work with module_load_include

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm building a custom module that uses functions from other modules. Specifically the node_clone module. I'm building a custom module to clone a certain content type from a selected user to another selected user.

In my custom module I'm adding those lines:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node_clone', 'clone.pages');
clone_node_save($nid);
```

The function clone_node_save is defined in the module "node_clone", in the root folder of that module,

```
function clone_node_save($nid, $account = NULL) {
//Function Content
}
```

inside a file called clone.pages.inc

yet those 2 lines of code give me the error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function clone_node_save()**

I also tried making a function inside node_clone.module that calls clone_node_save but that gets the same error.

This is drupal 7

Comment: I just realized module_load_include is returning false

Comment: It is enabled. I can call functions from clone_node.module. And I can use the module in the backend.
But I cannot call functions from clone.pages.inc (which is an include in that module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include the file extension in the third argument.

So this:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node_clone', 'clone.pages.inc');
```

Should be this:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node_clone', 'clone.pages');
```

Comment: My bad, I tried that earlier and it gives the same result. And drupal_get_path('module', 'node_clone'); returns empty

Comment: Sounds like the node clone module is not enabled.

Comment: It is enabled. I can call functions from clone_node.module. And I can use the module in the backend. But I cannot call functions from clone.pages.inc (which is an include in that module)

Comment: Is there any way I can provide the full path to include this module? Its located in /sites/all/modules/contrib/node_clone

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong name for the module. The .info file says project = "node_clone", which I assumed was the machine name of the module (its also the name of the folder). But the actual module is called clone.module, And I noticed this name in the System table when I was checking the path for the clone module.

Cheers!